# Finding name of a popup window in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, popup

I am creating multiple popup windows for chatting. Now my problem is how to find uniquely from which SendMessage() is called from popup window for sending message  to other person. At least how to find the name of pop window.

Please help me so that I can move forward

Comment: Could you please provide more details? The question is quite vague, in my opinion. I'm not even sure what SendMessage() is. ;-) Is it a built in function? Something you wrote? Maybe explain more about what you're hoping to accomplish because there might also be a better alternative.

Comment: Are you trying to get find out the ```name``` variable of a previous call to ```window.open(name, url [, ...])```?

Comment: @line-o it's `(url, name [, ...])` :P

Comment: SendMessage() is not a built in function but a user defined method to send msgs using websocket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide your name to the window like this

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace);
myWindow=window.open('','MsgWindow','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("This window's name is: " + myWindow.name );
```

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

to just answer your question, it is the `name` property the `window` object.

```
window.name
```

Ex:

```
var myWindow = window.open('','someName','width=200,height=100');
myWindow.document.write("<p>This window's name is: " + myWindow.name + "</p>");
```